# Access SQL Query: Making two columns of the same values, but how do you exclude cases where column 1 = column 2?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here's a mock-up of my data:

```
  Product  ||  MFGR
     A     ||   1
     A     ||   2
     B     ||   1
     B     ||   3
```

From this data, I would like to find any and all possible "swap" combinations. For example, Product A can be made at MFGR 1 or 2. Likewise, Product B can be made at MFGR 1 or 3. From this, I would like to generate the following table:

```
  MFGR1  ||  MFGR2
    1    ||    2      \______ Swaps for Product A
    2    ||    1      /
    1    ||    3      \______ Swaps for Product B
    3    ||    1      /
```

I've gotten very close with the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Products].MFGR AS MFGR1, 
    [Products_1].MFGR AS MFGR2
FROM [Products] 
    LEFT JOIN [Products] AS [Products_1] ON [Products].[Product] = [Products_1].[Product];
```

However, this expectedly reports cases where MFGR1 = MFGR2:

```
  MFGR1  ||  MFGR2
    1    ||    1    ← want removed
    1    ||    2
    2    ||    1
    2    ||    2    ← want removed
    1    ||    3
    3    ||    1
    3    ||    3    ← want removed
```

---

First thing I did was going into Design View and added the criteria `=Not(MFGR1)` to MFGR2. That generated this SQL: `HAVING ((([Products_1].MFGR)=Not ([PRODUCTS_1].MFGR)=([MFGR1])));` but when I try to view it I get [HAVING clause [name] without grouping or aggregation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221793(v=office.12).aspx)

I added `GROUP BY MFGR1, MFGR2` like this article recommends, but then I get `Your query does not include the specified expression 'MFGR1' as part of an aggregate function`, [but from what I see](https://www.google.com/search?q=your%20query%20does%20not%20include%20the%20specified%20expression), this error should be resolved by including `MFGR1` in my `GROUP BY`.

My last-ditch effort was to create a new query built upon my initial query (without any criteria). Here's the SQL for that:

```
SELECT [Product Query].MFGR1, [Product Query].MFGR2
FROM [Product Query]
WHERE ((([Product Query].MFGR2)=Not ([Product Query].MFGR2)=([MFGR1])));
```

But, this makes all rows disappear.

Comment: Don't use a `HAVING`, use a `WHERE`. Your first idea was correct besides that. `WHERE [Products_1].MFGR <> [PRODUCTS_1].MFGR`

Comment: @JNevill I ended up using Aaron's solution below, but I tested and confirmed that this has the same result. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep! Since you are using an INNER JOIN they are functionally equivalent to one another. I'm glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `[Products].MFGR <> [Products_1].MFGR` to your join condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Products].MFGR AS MFGR1, 
    [Products_1].MFGR AS MFGR2
FROM [Products] 
INNER JOIN [Products] AS [Products_1] ON [Products].[Product] = [Products_1].[Product] 
                               AND [Products].MFGR <> [Products_1].MFGR;
```

Changed your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` to prevent a bunch of `NULL` values in your result set.  I think this is how you want it.

Comment: This gets me halfway there. It makes the duplicate entries in MFGR2 null, but the rows are still there. I tried going into design view to build a criteria to remove them, but design view doesn't support the `<>` operators, and I don't know enough SQL to make the criteria from scratch. Would you happen to know?

Comment: I just noticed you changed `LEFT JOIN` to just `JOIN`. I changed it, but I now get 'Syntax error in FROM clause." (and all I've done is delete the word `LEFT`).

Comment: Got it! I needed to change it to `INNER JOIN`, and now the null values are removed :) Thanks!

Comment: @MrMusAddict Sorry, ran to lunch - I replaced `JOIN` with `INNER JOIN` in my answer. I guess Access must require `INNER` (and it's technically standard to use `INNER JOIN` instead of just `JOIN` anyway).  I'm glad it worked for you.